# JavaScript Regex to get title and subtitle from text file

Tags: javascript, regex

I Have below text and its comes from *.text file:

**1) TEXTDATA.TXT**

```
A 57-year-old female presents to the office with fatigue, jaundice and dyspnea. On physical exam you note her face is pale. Laboratory testing shows slightly elevated MCV, increased LDH, indirect bilirubin, and reticulocytes. Positive Direct Coombs test shows antibodies on RBCs and peripheral smear shows spherocytes. What is the most likely diagnosis?

A. Glucose-6-phospate dehydrogenase (G6PD) deficiency
B. Vitamin B12 deficiency
C. Paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria (PNH)
D. Iron deficiency anemia
E. Autoimmune hemolytic anemia

The correct answer is (E) Autoimmune hemolytic anemia This patient most likely has warm autoimmune hemolytic anemia as evidenced by her positive Direct Coombs test, elevated MCV, increased LDH, indirect bilirubin, and reticulocytes. Warm autoimmune hemolytic anemias are idiopathic or associated with autoimmune processes (SLE), drugs, lymphoproliferative disorders (CLL) and typically present with severe anemia (pallor, jaundice, fatigue, dyspnea). Peripheral smear can show spherocytes.

Choice A (Glucose-6-phospate dehydrogenase (G6PD) deficiency) is incorrect. G6PD is a X-linked recessive disease, which is seen more commonly in males.

Choice B (Vitamin B12 deficiency) is incorrect. Pernicious anemia typically presents with peripheral neuropathy, fatigue, leg stiffness, ataxia, memory impairment, and depression.

Choice C (Paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria (PNH)) is incorrect. Paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria presents with intermittent dark colored urine in the morning.

Choice D (Iron deficiency anemia) is incorrect. Iron deficiency anemia is associated with decreased Hgb, hematocrit, serum Fe, ferritin, transferrin saturation, and MCV, increased TIBC and RDW.


AUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA
Hemolytic anemia

Ax: 
Warm autoimmune hemolytic anemias are idiopathic or associated with autoimmune processes (SLE), drugs, lymphoproliferative disorders (CLL).
```

**1)** i've updated TEXTDATA.TXT and i am trying to find text between last "Choice X" to "Ax:" is there any easy trick that is worked. my code looks

```
var string = string.toString().substring(fileContent.indexOf("Choice E") + 8, string.indexOf("Cx:") - 3);
```

its little bit not working with last choice because choice is D "Choice D".

**2)** I need only Title = "AUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA" and Subtitle = "Hemolytic anemia" from TEXTDATA.TXT file It's Working perfect if i get content between last "Choice X" to "Ax:".

**Code:**

```
var ifdtdata = string.toString().substring(string.indexOf("Choice E") + 8, string.indexOf("Cx:") - 3);

titleifdt = /(?:\r?\n){2}([A-Z].*)/.exec(ifdtdata);
subifdt = /(?:\r?\n){2}([A-Z].*)\r?\n(.*)/.exec(ifdtdata);

ifdtdata = ifdtdata.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ,.?!]/ig, '');
if(valUndefinedNull(subifdt) == false){
       subifdt = /([A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z]{2,}?)([A-Z][a-z]+[^.]*)/.exec(ifdtdata);
}
if(valUndefinedNull(titleifdt) == false){
       titleifdt = /([A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z]{2,}?)([A-Z][a-z]+[^.]*)/.exec(ifdtdata);
}
```

Comment: Well in your example you would just pull off the 3rd line so no need for a regex (split())

Comment: Define what's "*It's little bit working*" supposed to mean. Also, create a test sample, because I still don't understand what are you trying to match and how.

Comment: It is possible that you are looking for a [`split`-based solution](http://jsfiddle.net/h8av1yef/2/).

Comment: I'm just curious... how did you manage to give `fileContent` the file input? Aren't you using any server-side language?

Comment: just text "AUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA" from test.txt and same as different files i have just used file reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need the contents of the second "meaningful" line. You can split the contents with a regex that will match any type of line breaks, and only grab the second element. Since there can be `\r` symbol in linebreaks, I suggest this sample code:

```js
var s = "TITLE X (CD55 and CD59 markers) are positive in paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria (PNH).\n\nAUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA\nHemolytic anemia\n\nTITLE Z: Warm autoimmune hemolytic anemias are idiopathic or associated with autoimmune processes (SLE)";
var arr = s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split(/[\r\n]+/);
document.write(arr[1]);
```

With `.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')`, you trim the input, and with `.split(/[\r\n]+/);` you can split the contents into separate lines be it a Windows/Linux/MacOS text file.

If you need the first line starting with an uppercase letter after the first double linebreak, use

```js
var s = "TITLE X (CD55 and CD59 markers) are positive in paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria (PNH).\n\nAUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA\nHemolytic anemia\n\nTITLE Z: Warm autoimmune hemolytic anemias are idiopathic or associated with autoimmune processes (SLE)";
var m = /(?:\r?\n){2}([A-Z].*)/.exec(s);
if (m !== null)
  document.write(m[1]);
```

Here, the regex matches:

- `(?:\r?\n){2}` - two line breaks
- `([A-Z].*)` - a line starting with an uppercase letter `[A-Z]` and then matching all symbols other than newline as many as possible (greedy). This value will be in `m[1]`.

**UPDATE**

To find the subtitle, use

```js
var s = "TITLE X (CD55 and CD59 markers) are positive in paroxysmal nocturnal hemoglobinuria (PNH).\n\nAUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIA\nHemolytic anemia\n\nTITLE Z: Warm autoimmune hemolytic anemias are idiopathic or associated with autoimmune processes (SLE)";
var m = /(?:\r?\n){2}([A-Z].*)\r?\n(.*)/.exec(s);
if (m !== null){
  document.write("Title: " + m[1] + "<br/>Subtitle: " + m[2]);
}
```

Comment: Also, you can try to find "Hemolytic anemia" from test1.txt ?

Comment: I have updated the regex solution to include the subtitle.

Comment: Good, That's amazing can you tell me the trick how you are doing it and it works.

Comment: Having this kind of string sometimes 
VITAMIN B12 DEFICIENCYâ€¨Hemolytic anemia.
then it returns null.

Comment: I am on a mobile, can't check, but you can create an alternation group like (?:\r?\n|â€¨)

Comment: Ok no problem, thanks for your support but Have tryed to added group of |â€¨ this character javascript gives errors, like Invalid regular expression: missing /

Comment: Try [`var m = /(?:\r?\n){2}([A-Z].*?)(?:\r?\n|â€¨)(.*)/.exec(s);`](http://jsfiddle.net/zc06cnLy/)

Comment: sorry, leave â€¨ but my original string looks and i get like this without \n or new line means in one line AUTOIMMUNE HEMOLYTIC ANEMIAHemolytic anemia

Comment: This is becoming impossible, but under some circumstances [you can still find a match](http://jsfiddle.net/zc06cnLy/3/).

Comment: yes, i've used this condition also i have do it after getting string data string.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ,.?!]/ig, ''"); then last match is worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96513/discussion-between-kamani-rahul-and-stribizhev).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96549/discussion-between-kamani-rocky-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 0):

Here i just spil al the new lines and take the thirt (its start with 0 so the thirth is 2)

```
var title = fileContent.split("\n")[2]
console.log(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just match for line in all caps, and only take first match: [`/^\[A-Z\W 0-9\]{3,}$/m`](https://regex101.com/r/fW1zH4/1)

Comment: It would be shorter as `^[^a-z]{3,}$`. But, what if the first line is all in upper letters?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I followed OP's idea which indicates that only the title is in all capitals. I don't know what all the input looks like - he should. And he used `[A-Z]` match.

Comment: giving null output, with replace or matching string.